# iOS playback audioServices

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a working `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` code to run a 10s background music.
Is there a way for me to loop this audio every 10s ? I want it to run forever until an action is triggered to stop the audio (e.g: a button is pressed to stop the loop)

I read an article about `dispatch_after` and thought that it might be an appropriate way to create the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to AVAudioPlayer instead.  Not only can you specify a number of times to play the sound, but you have more control over the sound, including volume level.

It isn't that much harder.  For example, here is how you would play a sound, looped indefinitely:

```
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [{AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: nil];
    player.numberofLoops = -1;
    [player play];
```

and this is how you would stop it:

```
    [player stop];
```